# Diffeomorphisms vs homeomorphisms of 3-manifolds

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, at.algebraic-topology, smoothing-theory, 3-manifolds

For a smooth 3-manifold $M$, is the natural map from the space of diffeomorphisms of $M$ to the space of homeomorphisms of $M$,

$${\sf Diff}(M) \longrightarrow {\sf Top}(M),$$

a weak homotopy equivalence? Equivalently, is the space of smooth structures on a topological 3-manifold contractible? (This is as opposed to just connected, which is the usual statement of Moise's theorem.)

Comment: What definition of "space of smooth structures" are you using? Shouldn't it just be a single point?

Comment: Here's one definition: let ${\sf Mfld}_3^{\sf sm}$ be the topological groupoid of smooth 3-manifolds with diffeomorphisms, and let ${\sf Mfld}_3$ be the topological one. Let $B$ be the classifying space functor. Then there is a natural map of spaces

$$B{\sf Mfld}_3^{\sf sm} \longrightarrow B{\sf Mfld}_3.$$ One definition of the space of smooth structures on $M$ is that it is the homotopy fiber of this map, over the point $\{M\}$ in the base. One reference, for example, is Weiss & Williams' paper, Automorphisms of Manifolds. (This space is naturally a homotopy type , not a homeomorphism type.)

Comment: (Sorry about my first answer.  I got turned around.)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

$\mathsf{Diff}(S^3)$ is homotopy equivalent to $O(4)$, by Hatcher's solution to the Smale Conjecture: Hatcher, Allen E. A proof of the Smale conjecture, Diff(S3)≃O(4). Ann. of Math. (2) 117 (1983), no. 3, 553–607.

Cerf proved that the Smale conjecture implies that $\mathsf{Diff}(M) \to \mathsf{Homeo}(M)$ is a weak equivalence for all $3$--manifolds $M$, in J. Cerf, Sur les difféomorphismes de la sphère de dimension trois  ( $\Gamma_4$ = 0 ), Lecture Notes in 
Math., vol. 53, Springer-Verlag, Berlin and New York, 1968, I think.  See [Linearization in 3-Dimensional Topology](http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1978.1/Main/icm1978.1.0463.0468.ocr.pdf) by Hatcher.